# How Can I enable Authentication of username and password on Selenium Grid Hub Url?

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid, zalenium

I am wondering if we can put the authentication on the selenium grid hub url by asking username and password before entering into the selenium Grid hub ?

Can this be also done if we are using the Zalenium grid which internally uses the Selenium Grid ?

Will it ask for username and password everytime we access the selenium grid hub ?

Can we also enable SSO based authentication on the selenium grid hub url ?

Can we also use JWT token for the authentication on the selenium grid hub url ?

Comment: You can set up passwords using [ROUTER_USERNAME and ROUTER_PASSWORD](https://www.webelement.click/en/selenium_grid_4_complete_guide_to_configuration_flags#_router_flags) flags.

Comment: Also you can set up a reverse-proxy between your client code and a hub that would implement any sort of authentication you need.